# Evaluate instance variable in block passed to class_eval through wrapper

Tags: ruby

I want to extend the functionality of a method `asdf` at runtime.
A method `append_asdf` should allow modifying the method more easily.

I understand how to call the previous method but the private variable `@b` evaluates to `nil` inside the block used to specify the additional behaviour - if passed through the wrapper.
It works as expected when passed to class_eval directly (which is not what I want).

Why?

```
class A
  def initialize
    @b = "144"
  end

  def asdf
    puts "12"
  end

  def self.append_asdf(&n)
    m = instance_method(:asdf)
    define_method(:asdf) { 
      m.bind(self).call
      n.call
    } 
  end
end

a = A.new

p = proc {
  puts @b
}
```

The proc `p` is used here to drive home the point that it doesn't depend on the block. It behaves the same as a literal.

This doesn't work:

```
A.append_asdf(&p)
a.asdf
=>
12
```

Note the empty line. The same proc used here evaluates as expected:

```
A.class_eval {
  define_method(:asdf, p)
}
a.asdf
=>
144
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to evaluate that block in the proper context. In other words:

```rb
instance_eval(&n)
```

Instead of a regular `call`.

Comment: i thought i already did that - and now i feel very stupid... :-D
thanks for your time